# python/pandas venv : error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required

Tags: python, pandas, python-venv

I am trying to create a virtual environment (venv) that uses an older version of pandas that matches what we have on the servers where my script is deployed in production. I have not used virtual environments before, but with some recent changes I made to a project I maintain, I made some changes that worked locally, but did not work in production.

I created a venv, and then started installing packages into it, I was attempting to install pandas version 0.25.0, but I got an error `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/`.

I guess it's not a problem to simply download the build tools, but before I do I just wanted to understand if my current version of pandas(1.4.4) also needs those tools and which version. On my machine, I have this dir `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio`, but I can't tell if that is what my current version of pandas is using or if the VS requirement no longer exists...

At any rate, I guess my question is, if I download and install the Visual C++ 14.0, for use in my virtual env, will that cause an issue in my regular python/pandas install?

thanks!

Comment: Perhaps the version of python has to be between 3.5 and 3.7? [Download files - pandas 0.25.0](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/0.25.0/#files)

Comment: It's not Visual Studio, it's Visual C++. Download and install it as the instructions say